# How can I change the chart color using events (google charts)

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Is it possible to change the color of the series through the event?

In this example I trigger an alert and a log just to see how it works, but I would like to know if it is possible to change the color of the selected option.

**Simple example:** click on sales and the event changes the color from blue to green

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2013',  1000,      400],
          ['2014',  1170,      460],
          ['2015',  660,       1120],
          ['2016',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

                function selectHandler(e) {
        console.log(chart.getSelection()[0]);
                alert('A table row was selected');
                }
        
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, a couple things...

1. chart events should be applied, before the chart is drawn.
2. the `'select'` event is called both when a point is selected, and when it is unselected.
   as such, you need to check the length of the selection, before trying to access the contents of the array.
   otherwise, when a point is unselected, an error would occur, here --> `chart.getSelection()[0]`

---

to set the series color, we can use the following config option.

```
series: {
  0: {  // <-- series number
    color: 'green'
  }
}
```

when the `'select'` event fires, we can use the `column` property from the selection to find the series number. it will be the column value - 1.

however, in order to change the series color, the chart must be re-drawn.
which means the selection will be removed.

we can use the `'ready'` event to reset the selection.
but in order to show the tooltip when the selection is reset,
we must use the following config option...

```
tooltip: {
  trigger: 'both'
}
```

---

see following working snippet,
when a point is selected, the selected series color is set to green, and the chart is re-drawn in the `'select'` event.
then the selection is reset in the `'ready'` event...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2013', 1000, 400],
    ['2014', 1170, 460],
    ['2015', 660, 1120],
    ['2016', 1030, 540]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Year',
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#333'
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      minValue: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'both'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  var selection = [];

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', readyHandler);

  function readyHandler() {
    chart.setSelection(selection);
  }

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

  function selectHandler() {
    selection = chart.getSelection();
    options.series = {};
    if (selection.length > 0) {
      options.series[selection[0].column - 1] = {
        color: 'green'
      };
    }
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

  chart.draw(data, options);
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#chart_div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```