# How to Change Style of Focused Point in Google Charts Scatter Plot

Tags: charts, google-visualization, scatter-plot

I've created a Scatter Plot using Google Charts. I can successfully format the points to look how I want. However, I can't figure out how to change the style of the focused point only. For instance, I can specify all points to be drawn as white circles, but how do I make the point change to green when clicked?

```
function drawScatterPlot (table_arguments={}) {
              
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('number', table_arguments["xtitle"]);
    data.addColumn('number', table_arguments["ytitle"]); // Required to be a number
    data.addColumn( {'type': 'string', 'role': 'style'} ); // Defines point style
    
    let pointStyle = 'point { size: 12; shape-type: circle; fill-color: #FFFFFF; color: #CCCCCC }';
    
    for (let [index, row_data_i] of Object.entries(row_data)) {
        row_data_i[2] = pointStyle;
    }
    
    data.addRows(table_arguments["data"]);
    
    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: table_arguments["title"],
            subtitle: table_arguments["subtitle"]
        },
        hAxis: {title: table_arguments["xtitle"]},
        vAxis: {title: table_arguments["ytitle"]},
        legend: {position: 'none'},
        trendlines: {  0: { opacity: 0 }}
    };
    
    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('scatterchart_material'));

    // DRAW CHART
  
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: there are no standard options for this. on the `'select'` event, you could try either changing the svg for the point manually, or change the style of the point and re-draw the chart, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62759679/5090771)...